# Data.table regex matching overlapping text by group

Tags: r, regex, text, data.table

Ok, I have a relatively complex one. A `data.table` solution would be most welcome but anything goes really. Just copy paste the reproducible example of the `input` and the `output` data.tables.

I would like to group by `uniqueID` but the twist is that I would want all rows of `Description` with the **same group** matching any overlapping **word or phrase** and only assign this to the retained record. Hopefully the example is self explanatory. One important point is that I am indifferent of the order the words or phrases appear.

Example:

```
> input_x
      uniqueID Sourced_from                                                                               Description
1: RandomHash1          DB1                                           This is an example of what I would like to keep
2: RandomHash1          DB1            That is another example of what I would like to keep -; random text added here
3: RandomHash2          DB2 All of these examples depend on the uniqueID and I need to only keep the overlapping part
4: RandomHash2          DB2                                                                          Overlapping part
5: RandomHash3          DB1                 This should be on its own because its hash is non associated with another
> output_x
      uniqueID Sourced_from                                                               Description
1: RandomHash1          DB1                                   is example of what I would like to keep
2: RandomHash2          DB2                                                          Overlapping part
3: RandomHash3          DB1 This should be on its own because its hash is non associated with another
```

Reproducible example code:

```
library(data.table)
    input_x <- setDT(structure(list(uniqueID     = c("RandomHash1",    "RandomHash1", "RandomHash2", "RandomHash2",  "RandomHash3" ), 
                    Sourced_from = c("DB1", "DB1",   "DB2",    "DB2",   "DB1" ),
                    Description  = c("This is an example of what I would like to keep",
                                     "That is another example of what I would like to keep -; random text added here",
                                     "All of these examples depend on the uniqueID and I need to only keep the overlapping part",
                                     "Overlapping part",
                                     "This should be on its own because its hash is non associated with another")
),
.Names    = c("uniqueID", "Sourced_from", "Description"),
class     = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -5L)
))

output_x <- setDT(structure(list(uniqueID    = c("RandomHash1", "RandomHash2",  "RandomHash3" ), 
                          Sourced_from = c("DB1", "DB2",   "DB1" ),
                          Description  = c("is example of what I would like to keep",
                                           "Overlapping part",
                                           "This should be on its own because its hash is non associated with another")
),
.Names    = c("uniqueID", "Sourced_from", "Description"),
class     = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -3L)
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a function that splits the string and intersects it to find common words, and use `data.table` to apply it, i.e.

```
library(data.table)

f1 <- function(x) {
    i1 <- Reduce(intersect, strsplit(tolower(x), split = '[[:punct:]]|\\s'))
     return(paste(i1, collapse = ' '))
}


input_x[, .(Description = f1(Description)), by = .(uniqueID, Sourced_from)][]
```

which gives,

> ```
>       uniqueID Sourced_from                                                               Description
> 1: RandomHash1          DB1                                   is example of what i would like to keep
> 2: RandomHash2          DB2                                                          overlapping part
> 3: RandomHash3          DB1 this should be on its own because its hash is non associated with another
> ```

Comment: Sotos, I don't know how simple this seemed to you but it was certainly not trivial for me. You saved me from quite a headache and for that I am grateful.

Comment: Happy to help. The only flaw of the above is that it converts your words to lower case so that it will not miss matches like `overlapping` and `Overlapping`